# Generating random values from a set of values according to the percentage distribution

Tags: java, random

So I'm trying to randomly assign a single value from a array of values to a variable but the values should be assigned according to a defined percentage distribution. For example,
If we have the values ["cat", "dog", "mouse"] with their percentage distribution as [30,50,20] respectively. Now suppose I need to generate 10 values from the above array randomly. I want the values like:
1. dog
2. dog
3. mouse
4. cat
5. dog
6. cat
7. mouse
8. dog
9. cat
10. dog
So, even though the values have been generated randomly, the percentage distribution from the list is intact(cat-3 times, dog-5 times, mouse-2 times).
How can I implement this?

Comment: What have you tried? please attach your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We will help you solve specific, code-based problems.

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me, all I want to know is an approach that can be used.

Comment: @Codeer I have not tried anything yet as I'm not sure what approach I should use. All the examples that I have seen so far are for weighted random number generation, but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: Also if you want to generate the list random, you should look at java's `Math.Random`. But i am a bit confused because you want a random list but it always have to be a 2-3-5 distribution. Random (the name in general) doesn't guarantee that. Only the chances that something is picked. Obviously with a bigger set it is evened out slightly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some homework, so I'll give you a guideline of what you could do:

1. Generate a list with the items you need:: 3 cats, 5 dogs and 2 mice.
2. Shuffle the list.

This should give you the amounts that you are after.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I thought of using this approach, but the problem is, generating the list first and then shuffling it works when the list to be generated is small( say 10 or 100). But when the list to be generated is very huge( say 100k or more), I'm not sure how it will behave. Is there a way where we can randomly generate the value keeping the ratio intact?